# How to change the progress drawable of SeekBar dynamically from the program?

Tags: android

I would like to change the color of the progress (not the `SeekBar` background) of a `SeekBar` dynamically from the program.

Using `seekbar.setProgressDrawable(Drawable drawable)` only changes the background of the `SeekBar`. All the examples I've seen make use of drawables from XML which are static at runtime.

The color changes according to some user activity and I need to set this to the progress drawable of the seekbar. So I'm programming my own drawable in my code.

In XML, we can specify the item IDs (such as background, progress, etc.) to get a drawable? How to achieve this in program?

Answer (score 1):

You can create  your custom xml, then setbackgrounddrawable of your progressbar programatically,

myProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(R.drawable.progress_horizontal);

***progress_horizontal.xml***

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                    android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#ff747674"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                        android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                        android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                        android:centerY="0.75"
                        android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                        android:angle="270"
                />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                        android:startColor="#ffffd300"
                        android:centerColor="#ffffb600"
                        android:centerY="0.75"
                        android:endColor="#ffffcb00"
                        android:angle="270"
                />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
```

Comment: As I've already mentioned in my question this solution doesnt solve my problem. I need to change the progress drawable of the seekbar based on user input at all times. The XML drawable can only set one static drawable. Even if I use my custom drawable from code it only changes the background of the seekbar not the progress